# Need an event when an element is being animated in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events, animation

There are some elements in my website that are animated by click. This animation takes about 3 seconds so users are able to animate multiple elements. I don't want them to be able to do such thing, I mean when an element is being animated I want to disable the rest of the elements. Is there anyway to trigger an event when an element is in the middle of the `animate` process?

Comment: You can check using pseudo selector `:animated`. This need to be tested if CSS3 animation/transition is used, i'm no more sure about that. That's said, setting a class on animated element and check for it would be a simple workaround

Comment: Usually this problem is solved the other way around. Stop the existing animations before starting new ones as to not have animations slowing down your users. Animations should complement your UI, not interfere with it.

Comment: Check [Animation Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations#Using_animation_events);

Comment: you can use .stop() and .finish() to pause/finish animations on the click of the elements.

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff your suggestion gave me the clue to the solution

Comment: @Drupalist Accept the answer that helped you for future users to find best solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you could just add a class when you animate element:

```
$('.someElementsToAnimate').on('click', function(){
    if($('.animating').length) return;
    $(this).addClass('animating').animate({/*...*/}, function(){$(this).removeClass('animating');});
});
```

Looks like you are over complicating what you are looking for.

Of course, if you want more specific answer, you have to provide relevant code, what you didn't do in question.

Comment: I also added my solution, how is it?

Comment: @Drupalist ya, using `:animated` works, btw, that was my first comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery for animation, you can call animate with callback options (start and complete)

https://api.jquery.com/animate/

for example

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    width: "toggle",
    height: "toggle"
  }, {
    duration: 5000,
    specialEasing: {
      width: "linear",
      height: "easeOutBounce"
    },
    start: function() {
      console.log('start animation');
    },
    complete: function() {
      console.log('end animation');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, which parameter handle what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```
$("some_elements").click(function(){
    if($(".animatable_elements").is(":animated"))
        return;


});
```